# Processe IIS log files from Azure storage container- using web job a good idea?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have azure log files with more than 250MB size each in one container(6 files per hour). I have cs program to access and process these log files. But what i am doing now is just taking only 100 lines from each log files(created in one hour). If i am processing the whole files, then i want to access almost 1.5GB of data. How can i handle this situation? My plan is to use a WebJob to create smaller files from this log files automatically and to store these files to a different container, and access that files from my cs program. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth I don't understand the problem- are you worried because of traffic or processing time?
In any case you can try to reduce file size by removing some fields in IIS log setup. Another option will be setting Log File Rollover to smaller size- this can minimize download time for processing.

Comment: My worry is all about processing this huge amount of data

Comment: Some time ago we were trying to use HDInsight for IIS logs analysis- solution appeared to be elegant, but way to complex :-)
Now we process files one by one, it appeared to be fine with our site upload.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is doable with a WebJob, but it sounds like the size of the file is the issue. Would a different log type be better for your scenario? Possibly using "Failed Request Tracing". You may also be able to change the verbosity level in the diagnostics config. For more info see:

[Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/)

[Azure Web App (Website) Logging - Tips and Tools](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/#.VWTmPc9VhBc)